# Running a Visual C++ 6 Console Application as a Windows Service

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Is it possible for a Win32 Console Application to be used as a Windows service?

Normally this wouldn't be an issue using C#, .NET, and Visual Studio 2010 or higher, but this is a legacy application that was written in C++ using the Visual C++ 6 environment.

Mainly for the ability to restart itself after a crash.

Comment: A Windows service application has to be written as such. It needs special entry-points that Windows will look for. Another option would be to develop such a service that monitors the first application and restarts it as needed.

Comment: Check out [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/)

Comment: The last version of Windows where services could interact with the UI was Windows XP. If you just want the application to restart if it's not running there are easier ways, for example the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for a Win32 Console Application to be used as a Windows service?

Yes.  In fact, many services are written as console apps.  Even MSDN examples are.

The app's `main()` simply needs to call [`StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324.aspx) to establish a link to the Service Control Manager:

[Writing a Service Program's main Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687416.aspx)

> Mainly for the ability to restart itself after a crash.

The correct way to handle that is to just let it crash. Use [`ChangeServiceConfig2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) to configure the service's `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS` info.  One of the available actions is `SC_ACTION_RESTART`.